# using list.files() in R to find files that start with a specific string

Tags: r, list, file

I am using `list.files()` in r to read in files. However, the `pattern=` input will scan all files that contain that special string I am scanning for...

Ex.

`MASTERLIST =list.files("/Volumes/3TB/",pattern="CL")`

will call in the following files:

```
[1] "CLF16"  "CLF17"  "CLF18"  "CLF19"  "CLG16"  "CLG17"  "CLG18"  "CLH16"  "CLH17"  "CLJ16"  "CLJ17"  "CLK16"  "CLK17"  "CLK18"  "CLM16"  "CLM17" 
[17] "CLM18"  "CLM19"  "CLN16"  "CLN17"  "CLQ16"  "CLQ17"  "CLU15"  "CLU16"  "CLU17"  "CLV15"  "CLV16"  "CLV17"  "CLX15"  "CLX16"  "CLX17"  "CLZ15" 
[33] "CLZ16"  "CLZ17"  "CLZ18"  "CLZ19"  "CLZ20"  "MCLH16" "MCLM16" "MCLU16" "MCLZ16"
```

But I only want those files that begin with `CL` and not every file that contains `CL` like files 38 through 41

How do I get it to call only those files that begin that pattern?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `pattern` argument takes a regex, so you can use: `pattern = "^CL"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Sys.glob` to use wildcard expansion and so to precise what you want:

```
Sys.glob('CL*')
```

should do the job you want.